# Sluggish performance on an Pavilion dv2210us Laptop with an Nvidia Geforce Go 6150

Tags: 11.10

I am a new Linux user after installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop.  I enjoy the new learning experience but currently experiencing a single problem - sluggishness on video performance.  I believe many people already asked this question again and again, but after searching through forums, I have not been able to resolve this issue. I hope you can help me.

*My Hardware Specifications*

HP Pavilion dv2210us Entertainment PC Laptop

AMD Turion X2 64 1.6Ghz

nVidia Geforce Go 6150 (integrated graphic chip)

2GB DDR3 RAMs 667Mhz

I did a fresh install on a separated partition and updated everything as required by Ubuntu.  By default, Additional Drivers installed version 173 for my graphic driver, which is the most stable except that it is sluggish when watching YouTube or any other videos on my backup hard drive.  Also, dragging/minimizing/maximizing/dragging-and-shaking just seems way too slow compared to my dual-boot Windows 7.

I pray that someone benign enough to help me resolve this issue as soon as possible and I will be a happy camper!  Thank you very much.

Here is the data generated from Ubuntu 11.10 Terminal with command, lspci -d10de: -vvnn

[Pavilion dv2210us Geforce Go 6150 Video Card Information](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1k6uy83YaTTvhiFAHfN--NOZKVdDFjlMBNwGpxY3hYL8)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Ubuntu in 2D mode? (Click on the gear next to the username and choose Ubuntu 2D). First run Ubuntu in 2D mode and go to the software center and download install the nvidia driver than when its installed go to additional drivers and make sure its checked green then restart. http://gnometechblog.weebly.com/